# Recovering the CDF of a Laplace Distribution with a specified PDF

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I'm working on finding the cumulative distribution function of a Laplace distribution with the following PDF:
$$f(x) = \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda\mid x-\theta\mid}, \ -\infty \lt x \lt \infty$$
I have attempted the following solution, however I am not sure whether it is correct:
$$
F_{X}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda\mid y-\theta\mid}dy
$$
Firstly find the indefinite integral via the substitution method:
$$
\frac{\lambda}{2}\int e^{u}du,\ u=-\lambda\mid y-\theta\mid \\
$$
The differentiation of $u$, $du$, works out to be $\frac{-\lambda y(y-\theta)}{\mid y- \theta \mid}$. Rewrite the integral in terms of $u$ and include $du$:
$$\frac{\mid y-\theta\mid}{-2y(y-\theta)}\int e^{u}du \\
=\frac{\mid y-\theta\mid}{-2y(y-\theta)}(e^{-\lambda\mid y-\theta\mid} + C)
$$
With that done, the definite integral I think is as follows:
$$F_X(x) = \frac{\mid x-\theta\mid}{-2x(x-\theta)}(e^{-\lambda\mid x-\theta\mid} + C)$$
Could someone help with verifying this? I am unsure if I made a mistake in finding the indefinite integral.

Comment: how can a cdf be negative ?

Comment: Oh, darn -- I guess I made a mistake in deriving $u$?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution), letting parameter $b = 1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume first that $x < \theta$, then

\begin{align*}
F_{X}(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda(y-\theta)}dy
=\frac{1}{2}e^{\lambda ( x- \theta)}.
\end{align*}

Then, for $x \ge \theta$, we have

\begin{align*}
F_{X}(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda|y-\theta|}dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\theta}\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{\lambda(y-\theta)}dy
+ \int_{\theta}^{x}\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda(y-\theta)}dy\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-\lambda(x-\theta)})\\
&= 1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-\lambda (x - \theta)}
\end{align*}